# Recaptcha v3 - error in recaptcha_en.js Unknown base64 encoding at char:

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

Around six months ago several sites that I maintain using recaptcha v3 starting throwing this error when dev tools are open.

It does not affect the operation of recaptcha but it's annoying when trying to use dev tools.

As far as I can tell from the call stack, the string isn't passed in (at least, not as is). I can only find two other reports that look like the same issue so it seems unlikely to be a recaptcha bug, and as neither have answers they're not much help.

[image: function throwing error] [image: top level function creates string deemed invalid]

All the pages that exhibit the error are utf-8 encoded. They use different versions of jquery, bootstrap and so on, so it's hard to find a candidate for a possible conflict.

Suggestions for moving forward to resolving the error would be welcome.

Comment: I had the same issue. I went crazy about it.  Finally, I found out, that everything works OK, if I just close Dev tools ...

Comment: Even better would be if Dev Tools had a setting to 'ignore only the annoying recaptcha error and stop on everything else'